# Fixing the unit step function in ifthenelse statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, fourier

Consider the following line of code :

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 4 * pi,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5,
    domain = 0 : 3 * pi,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = $f(t)$,
 legend style={at={(0.8,1)},anchor=north west},
    axis x line = center, 
    axis y line = center,
    every axis x label/.append style = {below},
    every axis y label/.append style = {left},
    samples = 100,
    xtick = {0, 3.14, 6.28, 9.42},
    xticklabels = {$0$, $\quad\;\;\pi$, $\quad 2\pi$,$3\pi$},
    declare function = {
      f(\x) = ifthenelse(pi<\x < 2*pi ,-1,1);
      f_{1}(\x) = (4 / pi) * sin(deg(\x);
      f_{3}(\x) = f_{1}(\x) + (4 / pi) * sin(3 * deg(\x)) / 3.0));
      f_{5}(\x) = f_{3}(\x) + (4 / pi) * sin(5 * deg(\x)) / 5.0));
    }, ]
    \addplot[thick, black] {f(x)};
    \addplot[thick,dotted, ultramarine] {f_{1}(x)};
    \addplot[thick,dotted, retropurple] {f_{3}(x)};
    \addplot[thick,dotted, cyan] {f_{5}(x)};
    \legend{$f(t)$, $f_1(t)$, $f_3(t)$, $f_5(t)$};    
     \draw[gray, dashed] (5*pi, 0.5) -- (5 * pi, 0.5);
    \draw[gray, dashed] (5* pi, 0) -- (5 * pi, 1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

(Please ignore the color definition here). The output of this code gives :
[image]

The issue is with the step function being graphically incorrect (thich black line) because of the ifthenelse statement I don't know how to fix this small issue where I should obtain the following :

An output of 1 for t between 0 and pi

An output of -1 for t between pi and 2pi

An output of 1 for t between 2pi and 3pi

and any help would be much appreciated. I further apologize for my previous post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Your approach does work, however, it seems you need to rephrase the `ifthenelse` statement a little bit. Also, note that to use this statement, you don't need to load the `ifthen` package. The following should work as expected (I changed the colors to default ones and commented out the `center` environment):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 4 * pi,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5,
    domain = 0 : 3*pi,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = $f(t)$,
    legend style = {at = {(0.8,1)}, anchor = north west},
    axis x line = center, 
    axis y line = center,
    every axis x label/.append style = {below},
    every axis y label/.append style = {left},
    samples = 100,
    xtick = {0, 3.14, 6.28, 9.42},
    xticklabels = {$0$, $\quad\;\;\pi$, $\quad 2\pi$, $3\pi$},
    declare function = {
      f(\x) = ifthenelse(and(pi < \x, \x < 2 * pi), -1, 1);
      f_{1}(\x) = (4 / pi) * sin(deg(\x);
      f_{3}(\x) = f_{1}(\x) + (4 / pi) * sin(3 * deg(\x)) / 3.0));
      f_{5}(\x) = f_{3}(\x) + (4 / pi) * sin(5 * deg(\x)) / 5.0));
    }, ]
    \addplot[thick, black] {f(x)};
    \addplot[thick, dotted, blue] {f_{1}(x)};
    \addplot[thick, dotted, purple] {f_{3}(x)};
    \addplot[thick, dotted, cyan] {f_{5}(x)};
    \legend{$f(t)$, $f_1(t)$, $f_3(t)$, $f_5(t)$};
    \draw[gray, dashed] (5 * pi, 0.5) -- (5 * pi, 0.5);
    \draw[gray, dashed] (5 * pi, 0) -- (5 * pi, 1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't fully understand, why you need to split up the inequation chain, but I guess that it always returns true since `pi` is always smaller than `2 * pi` (regardless of what `\x` is).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely take note about writing down the equations in a better way next time

Comment: You are welcome. However, I could not answer why this does not work. Maybe someone else can explain this ...